# Rule Sonar to respect tree structure project

Tags: android, ios, sonarqube, rules, sonar-runner

I'm starting working with Sonar to validate my mobile projects and now i'm learning about [custom rules](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules).

I'm trying create a rule to check if the path of file is correctly.. Its is possible?

Example: my **Xibs** files in the same folder of **ViewControllers** files